# Calculating the probability of an element being in 2 subsets

Tags: probability, probability-theory, education

I've just started to learn about "Probability-Theory" and came across this problem that i want to calculate. 
I've given a total amount of 28 million elements. Following information is given: In total there are 2562 elements with Attribute A and 3 elements with the Attribute B. Now how can i calculate the probability that one randomly drawn element has BOTH Attributes A and B 
And how does the probability behave if I draw X elements (without replacement).

I've also drawn a little picture to visualize my problem.

Thanks in advance,

Koapsii

Edit: The Attributes are randomly distributed. So:
Step 1: Go through the 28 mil and distribute Attribute A randomly 
Step 2: Go through the 28 mil and distribute Attribute B randomly 
Step 3: Calculate amount/likelihood that an element has Attribute A AND B

The problem is about IT Security. In total there are 28 mil software entities, researches estimated that there are ~2562 hidden vulnerabilities (so called ZeroDay vulnerabilities) in these software entities and now I want to find out what's the chance that one of my 3 software entities is affected by those 2562 hidden vulnerabilities. There is no way i can look that up, because this is exactly what i want to know. The chance of being affected

[image: probability]

Comment: You should clarify how many elements there are in a sample.

Comment: Well, as I've said: "one randomly drawn element", so the sample has 1 element to understand the idea behind the formula. And after that, I would like to know how the probability calculation behaves with X elements in the sample

Comment: You just asked this question, didn't you?

Comment: @saulspatz yes I did, but people asked me to reopen the question, since I had some wrong formulations in it.

Comment: When that happens, it's better to edit the original question.  This way, all the previous discussion is lost.  Still, you have the same problems in this formulation: 1) we don't know how many objects have both attributes . 2) Your answer can't possibly be right.  Look at the denominator.  It's far greater than the number of objects in the sample space.  There simply isn't enough information given to answer the question.

Comment: @saulspatz So if i want to calculate the number of objects that have the both attributes, what further information do I need?

Comment: That depends on the problem.  Suppose you know that in your school 150 students are taking math, and 180 students are taking physics.  How many are taking both math and physics?  How could we hope to calculate that?  We have to ask the registrar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation assumes that having attribute A and attribute B are independent.  It would apply if you went through the elements and gave them attribute A with probability $\frac {2562}{28,000,000}$ and attribute B with probability $\frac {3}{28,000,000}$.  Given that you have the sample and exact numbers with each attribute they can't be independent.  If there is one that has both attributes, given a $B$ the chance it is an $A$ is (at least) $\frac 13$.  If there are none with both attributes the chance that a $B$ is also an $A$ is $0$.  Both of these are different from $\frac {2562}{28,000,000}$.

Comment: Well, i only know that there are 2562 elements with Attribute A and 3 elements with Attribute B within these 28 million elements. So i assume that they are independent. It could be that all 3 elements with Attribute B also have Attribute A or that none of the elements with Attribute B have Attribute A. But i somehow need the amount of Attributes that have A and B. Or atleast how likely it is that there is an element with Attribute A and B

Comment: If you randomly pick without replacement $2562$ to give $A$ to and then pick without replacement $3$ to give $B$ to, the chance there is a match is very close to $\frac {3\cdot 2562}{28,000,000}$.  To be exact, go through the $B$s, compute the chance that none is an A, and subtract from $1$.  It will be higher because you use up some non-As, so $1-(\frac {28,000,000-2562}{28,000,000}\cdot\frac {27,999,999-2562}{27,999,999}\cdot\frac {27,999,998-2562}{27,999,998})$.

Comment: Yes, i randomly pick 2562 elements without replacement  and give them Attribute A and then I randomly pick 3 elements without replacement  and give them Attribute B. After the Attribute Distribution i take exactly one element out of the 28 million and therefor i want to know the chance that this certain element has both Attributes.
As far as I understand your formula, it calculates the chance of 1 - Picking an element without Attribute. But does this consider that i only pick ONE element after the attribute distribution?

Comment: No, this is the chance there is an element that is both an A and a B.  It includes the chance there are two, but that is tiny.  Then there is $1/28,000,000$ chance you pick that element

Comment: Ohhhhh, now I understand. I guess you saved my week.

Comment: To drive this further: Now my Subset B consists of 3 different classes. e.g Class 1, Class 2, Class 3. After calculating the probability with $1-(\frac {28,000,000-2562}{28,000,000}\cdot\frac {27,999,999-2562}{27,999,999}\cdot\frac {27,999,998-2562}{27,999,998})$ that atleast one element has both attributes A and B, I want to know the probability that this element with both attributes is either Class 1, Class 2 or Class 3. Do i think correctly If i just multiply this by 1/3?